# i get keyerror on 'time' when trying to scatter plot, how to scatter plot time?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I get a keyerror on 'time' when i try to scatter plot, how do i scatter plot these columns?

```
 high      time
0    17.23  10:37:00
1    17.64  14:01:00
2    15.28  09:31:00
3    15.56  11:41:00
4    15.56  11:42:00
5    15.25  09:30:00
6    15.25  09:49:00
7    15.10  15:52:00
8    16.41  10:40:00
9    17.75  15:09:00
10   17.75  15:10:00
11   19.20  09:41:00

df_high.plot.scatter(x='time', y='high', c=None, s=None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I suspect the dtype isn't being set automatically. Check with `df['time'].dtype`. You probably want the `datetime` dtype. Can convert with something like `pd.to_datetime`, or better yet load the data with the appropriate dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index('time').sort_index().plot(style='.')
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou...that works. Just so i understand a little better, my 'time' column is probably not datetime format?  or, should i have my 'time' column as the index?

Comment: @RossDemtschyna yes , at least using index is the most safe way .